# 404 handler and dynamic pages that really don't exists... bad for SEO?

Tags: iis, dynamic, seo, http-status-code-404, handler

We have an IIS 404 asp.net handler that renders pages when an html page is not found. It uses the page's URL to query our Databases and builds rich relevant content on the fly.  From what I can tell in the IIS logs and anaylyzing the pages from web browser tools there is NO indication the page does not actually exist and was dynamically generated.

In these cases is IIS actually sending a 404 to the client? Is there a redirect of any kind actually happening? Will Search engines punish me for this?

It's been 2 months and Google has indexed everything, but Bing and Yahoo have not indexed anything dynamic dispite my submitting various Directory pages, Sitemaps and Feeds with all my links.  My home page is indexed on all search engines and has all my links. When I search very unique keywords in those links, I can see that bing and yahoo do see them on my Home Page links - but only there.

Is there anything I can run or check to make sure my dynamic pages are not somehow viewed as bad by Search engines? Any way to check if a 404 (whatever a 404 actually is to a client besides just another page) is returned to crawlers?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything I can run or check to make sure my dynamic pages are
>   not somehow viewed as bad by Search engines?

Dynamic pages are just fine. Most of the content on the Internet is dynamically produced. The search engines don't care if content is dynamic and, in fact, they usually do not know content is dynamic as all they see if the URL and the HTML that is produced by that URL.

> Any way to check if a 404 (whatever a 404 actually is to a client
>   besides just another page) is returned to crawlers?

Use a tool like Firebug or the built in developer tools in Chrome to view your HTTP headers. Crawlers see the same headers a browser would see so that is an easy way to tell what headers your pages are sending out.

Comment: Thank you. I just checked one of the dynamic pages in firebug.. everything looks fine I guess. specifically what am i looking for and where? Also, I just moved all my iis logs to odbc. By chance woudl you know if I can find and maybe change the W3SVC##### service names for each site to some friendly name? If not I have to develop a map to be able to report. And finally (sorry) would you know if it's okay to a sitemap.ashx (a dynamic sitemap file that's not a xml file, but produces xml) in my robots.txt file?

Comment: In firebug click on the "Net" tab. Then click on "All". Refresh the page and then click on the first + icon you see (it should say something like GET example.html). Look where it says "Response Headers" to see the HTTP headers for that page.

Comment: FF noob here. How do  stop top menus from disappearing. Also, even if I run FB in it's own window when I page refresh FB asks if I want to attach.. but by then it's too late. perhaps a symptom of these dynamic pages maybe?

Comment: Dynamic pages are no different then any other page for firebug or any web browser since they only see the HTML the page produces (as mentioned in my answer). The top menus should stay open upon page refreshes. I am not sure what would cause it to not stay open so I can't really offer any troubleshooting tips other then to restart the browser and try again.